# Timeseries collection for mongodb design

Tags: mongodb, time-series

I want to create a time-series collection in MongoDB with the following fields:
`_id`, `locationId`, `machineId`, `timestamp`, `eventId`, `parameter`

So, will have around 5000 machines in 5000 locations (so the count of `locationId` and `machineId` will be around 5000).

Each machine produces around 200 documents in around 15-second intervals (with different `parameter` ranging from 1-16 and different `eventId` ranging from 0-1149)(so `timestamp` changes in millisecond levels). We poll data(200 documents per machine) every 15 seconds and insert it into the created collection.

I will make a report to display those records(in a paginated way) per `locationId/machineId` basis sorted by descending order of timestamp and people can apply the filters of timestamp and/or eventId(for eventId people can apply several filters like `equal to`, `not equal to`, `in`, `not in`, etc.)

So, based on the query, thinking of creating a compound index of the fields:

```
`{'machineId' : 1, 'timestamp': -1, 'eventId': 1}`
```

I am thinking of defining 'timestamp' as a time field, but not using any metadata field(as according to the official document metadata rarely changes but in our case we will around have 5000 `locationId` and `machineId`, and `parameter` ranging from  1-16 and  `eventId` ranging from 0-1149, so these parameter frequently changes as we will have around total 1 million records for 5000 devices every 10 seconds. Also, thinking of using `bucketMaxSpanSeconds` as 15 seconds.

What do you think of my decision? Should I declare at least `locationId/machineId` as `metaField`? Should I use the `granularity` field instead of custom  `bucketMaxSpanSeconds` ?